# Error: could not find function "Lag"

Tags: r, gam

While running `model0` found below I got an error message “ Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "Lag" . Before posting this message I have scanned this forum and the web, but could not find relevant solution. I believe the error in my model is not probably due to `Lag` function as other models (1 and 2) shown below could run without encountering any problem.

My main motive was to run a GAM model by looping  through a list of explanatory variables and their lags.

```
library(quantmod)
library(gamair) 
library(mgcv) 
data(chicago) 

names(chicago)

varlist0 <- c("pm10median", "pm25median", "o3median", "so2median")

model0<- lapply(varlist0, function(x) {
  gam(substitute(death ~ s(time,bs="cr",k=200)+ s(tmpd,bs="cr") + Lag(i,0:4) , list(i = as.name(x))),family=quasipoisson,na.action=na.omit, data=chicago)

})
```

**Gam + Lag with no error message:**

```
model1<- gam(death ~ s(time,bs="cr",k=200)+ s(tmpd,bs="cr") + Lag(pm10median, 0:4),family=quasipoisson,na.action=na.omit, data=chicago)
```

**Lm with Lag and no error message:**

```
hsb2 <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv")
varlist <- names(hsb2)[8:11]   
models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
    lm(substitute(read ~ Lag(i,0:4) , list(i = as.name(x))), data = hsb2)
})
```

I am unable to decipher the cause of this error. What have I done wrong in the first model?

Comment: thanks for the reproducible example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say the exact cause, but it has something to do with the environment in which `mgcv` is evaluating the formula. A safer approach than `substitute` is to do something like the following:

```
varlist0 <- c("pm10median", "pm25median", "o3median", "so2median")
model0 <- lapply(varlist0,function(v) {
    f <- sprintf("death ~ s(time,bs='cr',k=200)+s(tmpd,bs='cr') + Lag(%s,0:4)",v)
    gam(as.formula(f),family=quasipoisson,na.action=na.omit,data=chicago)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code works flawlessly. Struggling with this vague error message has taken my whole afternoon. I am grateful to you for your help.